# Call an object with special symbols python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, built-in

I have a question about how Python knows certain things. For example, when I write

```
a_list = ["car", "plane"]
print(a)
```

Python knows that a_list is a list. How does that work? where is it written in the default modules of python?

I want to create an object that works kinda like a list, but when I want to obtain the item in a specific position, I would want to write

```
object_list[0]
```

instead of a method like

```
object_list.obtain_item(0)
```

And I would want to create an object doing something like

```
$"car", "plane"$
# like yo do ["car", "plane"] by default
```

And I can't inherit from list cause it's prohibited in the project I'm working on.

Is this even possible? I was searching here and on the internet, but I can't even put my question in words to search properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, that would be a consequence of the implementation of the `__getitem__` method.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        if ind == 0:
            return self.x
        return self.y

x = Foo(1, 2)
print(x[0])
1

print(x[1])
2
```

Note that this is a very bare implementation, and I haven't used a list because you said you can't use it.

To answer your second question, that would involve making changes to the fundamental syntax and grammar of the language, which you, as an end user of the language, are currently not entitled to do.

Comment: thanks, __getitem__ was exactly the method i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

> Python knows that a_list is a list. How does that work? where is it
>   written in the default modules of python?

Python interpreter recognize the [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) literal and then create a list object. The Python list object is part of the "standard types that are built into the interpreter".

> I want to create an object that works kind like a list, but when i
>   want to obtain the item in a specific position, i would want to write

You can do that use [object.**getitem**(self, key)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). There is a lot of useful example on Internet.

> And i would want to create an object doing something like
>
> $"car", "plane"$
>
> like yo do ["car", "plane"] by default

If you don't want change the Python interpreter, you could have a less "native/hardcore" solution parsing the string and creating the objects that you want by yourself., something like:

```
>>> def my_parser(s):
...     return [i.strip('"') for i in s.strip('$').split(', ')]
... 
>>> my_parser('$"car", "plane"$')
['car', 'plane']
>>>
```